# Manipulating bits of a character variable

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

My objective is to frame a char variable by assigning values to each bit, i.e. I need to assign 0's and 1's to each bit.

I did the following code:

```
char packet;
int bit;
packet &= ~(1 << 0);

packet |= (1 << 1);

printf("\n Checking each bit of packet: \n");

for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
{
    bit = packet & (1 << x);
    printf("\nBit [%d] of packet : %d", x, bit);
}
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
Bit[0] of packet : 0
Bit[1] of packet : 2
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: This is what your code does.  Let g = garbage (i.e. uninitialized memory bit).  You start with "g g g g g g g g".  First bitwise operation creates "g g g g g g g 0" and second one does "g g g g g g 1 0".  And your loop simply prints out [0] = 0x00 (first bit is 0).  and [1] = 0x02 (second bit is 1).  So basically, as so many of us say on regular basis, "works as designed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem here, the output is correct.

Here's the reason:

When you set the value of packet with `|=`, the value is `10` which, in decimal, is 2. When you assign `packet & (1 << x)` to `bit`, you're actually assigning the value 2 (`10` in binary).

[Wikipedia entry:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

> To determine whether the second bit is
>   1, a bitwise AND is applied to it and
>   another bit pattern containing 1 in
>   the second bit:

```
    0011 (decimal 3) 
AND 0010 (decimal 2)   
  = 0010 (decimal 2)
```

If your intent is to simply check a boolean value of whether or not the bit has been set, simply cast it to a bool value.

(Hope that all made sense, I'm a little tired atm ;))

Answer (score 1):

First thing:

```
char packet;
packet &= ~(1 << 0);
```

This is not reliable, since `packet` starts off with whatever was in memory last (i.e. garbage). `1 << 0` is just `1`. `~1` is ...111110. Anding that with `packet` will give a different answer each time, depending on what was in memory last; the only sure thing is that the last bit (i.e. least significant) will be set to `0`.

```
packet |= (1 << 1);
```

This just sets the second bit to `1`. So now `packet` is `xxxxxx10`.

Your loop then goes over the first two bits; each bit is masked with `packet & (1 << x)`, but that *only* masks it, it does not move it around. So during the first iteration, `1 << x` is `1`, and you get the first bit (`0`). The second iteration, `1 << x` is `10`, or 2 in decimal. Anding `xxxxxx10` with `10` gives `10`, which you promptly print out (it appears formatted as `2`).

If you want to move the bit (in order to isolate it as a 0 or 1), you can use:

```
bit = (packet & (1 << x)) >> x;
```

Or the equivalent but more readable

```
bit = (packet >> x) & 1;
```

This will yield the (I'm assuming desired) output of `0`, `1` instead of `0`, `2`.

Answer (score 0):

That output appears entirely expected.  Bit 0 isn't set, Bit 1 is set.  Perhaps you're after

```
bit = !!(packet & (1 << x));
```

...if you want to get an `0` or `1` result.

By the way, you should initialise `packet` - use of an uninitialised variable results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Or just... you know `bit = packet>>x & 1;`